# Geogebra: Transformation of an image - translation matrix does NOT work ( rotation & scaling works fine )

Tags: matrices

I have created three 3x3 transformation matrices in Geogebra:

$$S=\begin{bmatrix}
sx&0&0\\
0&sy&0\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$R=\begin{bmatrix}
cos(\alpha)&sin(\alpha)&0\\
-sin(\alpha)&cos(\alpha)&0\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$T=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
x&y&1
\end{bmatrix}$$

When I use the `ApplyMatrix(S, pic1)` command, the `pic1` image scales as the `sx` and `sy` are varied, as expected.

When I use the `ApplyMatrix(R, pic1)` command, the `pic1` image rotates as the $\alpha$ is varied, as expected.

When I use the `ApplyMatrix(T, pic1)` command, the `pic1` **DOES NOT translate** as the `x` and `y` are varied.

I think this is because `pic1` is processed as a list of `{x,y}` vectors and it needs to be processed as a list of `{x,y,1}` vectors.

**Q**: How to get the translation matrix `T` to work properly with an image ?

P.S.
I need this 3x3 matrix in order to simulate the PDF matrix transformations described [here](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/pdfstandards/pdfreference1.7old.pdf) in Section 4.2.3 on Page 208.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct form of $T$ is as follows

$ T = \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && x \\ 0 && 1 && y \\ 0 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Thank you.  That indeed causes the tranlation to work properly.  Do you have any idea why that PDF matrix transformation documentation on Page 205 lists the last column of the matrix as always 0, 0, 1  ?

Comment: No idea. Must be an oversight.